# Formula not working on Google Sheets #error! Formula Parse Error

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have uploaded an excel spreadsheet that works fine but shows as an error on Google Sheets.

```
=SUM(H12,N12,T12,Z12,AF12,AL12)/INDEX(FREQUENCY((H12,N12,T12,Z12,AF12,AL12),0,2))
```

Its calculating average amount, but shows `#error!` and formula parse error.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UTuab6cEmw5Ct5N0t-V00kHYheA3IEgZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: parse error is due to wrong syntax

Answer (score -1):

```
=IFERROR(SUM(H10,N10,T10,Z10,AF10,AL10)/COUNTA(H10,N10,T10,Z10,AF10,AL10))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: hey that's not worked as it's not calculating the average amount over selected cells, whilst ignoring 0 or none entered.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Just the weekly average amount. I had the issue before in excel where I had to figure out how to exclude no date input or £0, hence the long formula.

Comment: formula from answer pretty much does that. can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: the formula doesn't work on Google sheets, it's showing as an outcome of £1.

Comment: for example if mon was 5, Tues wed and thurs 10 and Friday no input, the formula should work out the average is £8.75

Comment: @NickMorrison I see, answer updated